# How to apply on the draggable jQuery UI function on multiple items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I got a question regarding using the draggable function of jQuery UI. I got the following situation:

```
<div id="dragThis">
    <span>
        <b id="posX"></b> 
        <b id="posY"></b>
    </span>
 </div>
<div id="dragThis">
    <span>
        <b id="posX"></b> 
        <b id="posY"></b>
    </span>
 </div>
<div id="dragThis">
    <span>
        <b id="posX"></b> 
        <b id="posY"></b>
    </span>
 </div>
```

With this as JS code:

```
$('#dragThis').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        }
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t2y72baw/1/)

Dragging the first div works fine. But it will not work on the other div's. How can I achieve this? I need some kind of guidance how to drag the specific div.

I do not think the solution of setting for each div a different id and copying the draggable function for each div is a proper solution.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making it class instead id

```
<div class="dragThis">
```

id can not not be duplicated in a document. So you can do it using class. You also can write like :

```
<div id="dragThis" class="drag">
```

and refer to this class to draggable.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t2y72baw/3/